# Setting up a git repository on the same server that the code will be deployed to

Tags: git

I have git installed on my Ubuntu server and on my client. I'm planning to install git-flow as well.

When I create a project on the server, to where I will pull either the test branch or the production branch (both are on the same server), after I do the git init, what do I do about naming the remote, given that the repository is on the same server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cloning Git repository locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941090/cloning-git-repository-locally)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you clone it locally, the remote will be named for you.

```
git clone /path/to/repo
cd repo
git remote -v
```

You will see a remote named `origin`, referring to `/path/to/repo`.

That would be the same as:

```
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init .
git remote add origin /path/to/repo
git pull
```

Comment: So, when I create gits in the test deployment directory and the production deployment directory, which are on the same server as the repo, they point to the same remote with a local path? And I assume I create the repo with the --bare option?

Comment: @Ayen you create a repo with the --bare option only if you want to push to it. See http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html. Once create, that repo has no remote. If you clone the bare prod repo as "test" repo, *then* that repo has a remote referring to the prod repo. A repo refers its upstream repo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309.

Comment: Great, thanks. So to summarize, the repo that will be pushed to by developers and pulled from for deployment (like github) will not need a remote, and those pushing to it or pulling from it will identify it as the remote, with a url if not on the same server, or a local path if on the same server.

Comment: @Ayen sounds about right. When you *create* a repo (`git init`, or "create" on GitHub), it has no remote. But when you *clone* an upstream repo, it has a default remote named 'origin', with the url or local path you used to reference the upstream repo that you just cloned.