# Create a new local repo from existing project

Tags: java, git, repository

I have a new java project and want to push it on local repository on my pc(Not github or remote)for first time.
I used these commands
1: git init
2: git add .
3: git commit
4: git push

I pushed it successfully but just want to know what is this repository address(path) to clone or put it in other place?
thanks

Comment: what do you mean? the easiest way is to create a repo in your remote repository, and clone it to your drive. Why wouldn't you do it like that?

Comment: `git push` didn't do anything as you never set up a remote.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone a local repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922751/how-to-clone-a-local-repository)

Comment: See this also about how to push to remote if it does not exist. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382565/how-to-git-push-to-remote-if-remote-does-not-exist-at-all

Answer (score 0):

The basic operations of Git are established in remote warehouses, local warehouses, temporary storage areas, and workspaces. Your actions as above

1. `git init` The git init command initializes a local warehouse
2. `git add .` Temporarily store files in the current workspace to the temporary storage area
3. `git commit`git commit submits the staging area data to the local warehouse
4. `git push` git push submits the local warehouse data to the remote warehouse

The following is a very intuitive picture

[Command flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoi9C.jpg)

As shown in the figure, you can only pull and merge local warehouse data into the local workspace.

According to your needs, you can only build a git server locally, and you can access your locally built service through your ip address in the local area network.

Comment: I used these commands, but i don't know what is repository path to clone it on other place.

Comment: You must set up a local git service. At this time, your personal computer can act as a remote warehouse, and others can pull it through your ip, like a web application

Comment: @JerryHsu you can only do a git push if there already is a remote in place. Your answer doesn't really answer the question

Answer (score 0):

> want to push it on local repository on my pc(Not github or remote)for first time.

Then you need to create an empty *bare* repository (meaning a Git repo without any checked out file), which will serve as a remote to push to:

```
cd C:\repos
git init --bare my_new_repo.git

cd C:\path\to\existing\Git\repository
git remote add origin file://C/repos/my_new_repo.git
git push -u origin main
```

> what is this repository address(path) to clone or put it in other place?

it is using the [local file protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_the_protocols), hence its URL:

```
file://C/repos/my_new_repo.git
```